# pandas colume split by code and concat these data

Tags: pandas, financial

I'm pandas newbie

for example I have dataframe as below

```
code time open high low close
 1    2    1    1    1    1
 2    1    1    1    1    1
 2    2    1    1    1    1
```

and

1. I want column split by code
2. I want concat these splited data on index by time and fill NaN

like below

```
                    "1"                  "2"
time(index) open high low close  open high low close
     1      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1     1   1    1
     2       1    1    1    1     1     1   1    1
```

is there any way using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- first reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) or [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
- swap levels in `MultiIndex` in columns by [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)
- last sort columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

---

```
df = df.set_index(['time', 'code']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_index(1)
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.pivot('time', 'code').swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_index(1)
```

---

```
print (df)
code     1                    2               
     close high  low open close high  low open
time                                          
1      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2      1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```